# Is this sentence("He is a high thought guy") correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

I am having a confusion about expressing something like, a guy is intelligent and he thinks better and his thinking power is far better from anyone. I naturally wanted to express it like, "**He is a high thought guy**" and having confusion at the same time.

So I am asking for help. Is that sentence correct grammatically? If not, what would be the replacement then? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't say that, but what is wrong with "he is intelligent".

Comment: The problem is not so much with grammar as with vocabulary, Googling 'high thought' brings up a lot of references to people's thoughts when high on drugs! You could say "He is a man of great thinking power" (don't use 'guy' except in an informal context).

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you.

Comment: @JamesK Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like he is someone who _thinks highly of himself_, and that is not usually said kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly that isn't an idiomatic expression, not for what you are trying to say at least.

You might consider:

- he is a deep-thinker
- he is a deep-thinking guy
- he is deeply intelligent
- he is a deeply intelligent guy
- he is highly intelligent
- he is a highly intelligent guy

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

> "He is a high thought guy"

This is non-standard in two ways.

1. In purely grammatical terms, you would be more like to say "He is a high-thinking guy."
2. However "high-thinking", although grammatical,  is not idiomatic in English. You could say, "He is a highly intellectual guy.", "He is a highly intelligent guy."

Comment: Do you think, "he is a deep-thinking guy" would be idiomatic?

Comment: It's okay but unusual. Native speakers would probably say, "He's a deep thinker" as suggested by @Astralbee.  Given that you have already used "he", you don't need to say that he is a guy.

Comment: Thank you so much!